# Are 'contemporary' and 'contemplate' related words?

Tags: meaning, etymology, word-usage

Do the words *contemporary* and *contemplate* relate to each other in any way?

Comment: No, they have [different](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=contemporary&allowed_in_frame=0) Latin [roots](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=contemplate&allowed_in_frame=0).

Comment: Maybe an interesting question. -1 shows no research effort; where did you look before posting?

Answer (score 3):

The OED explains that ***contemplate*** comes from

> L. *contemplāre*, orig. deponent *contemplārī*, to survey, observe, behold, consider, contemplate, f. *con*- + *templum* ‘an open place for observation, marked out by the augur with his staff’

And that ***contemporary*** comes from:

> L. type *contemporāri-us*, f. *con*- together + *tempus*, *tempor*- time, *temporārius* of or belonging to time; the actual formations in L. were *contemporālis* and *contemporāneus*

So there seems no surface relationship between *tempus* and *templum*.

Comment: Wiktionary suggests *[tempus](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tempus#Latin)* and *[templum](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/templum#Latin)* have a shared Proto-Indo-European origin in  *temp- (“to stretch, string”)